# Prepaid Rent (Accrual Based Accounting)

Tags: accounting, accrual

I am running a small business that prepays office rent on the 25th of each month (for the next month).  I am using accrual based accounting with QuickBooks.

My question is, do I need to debit current assets/credit cash on the 25th of each month and then debit expenses / credit current assets at the end of the next month FOR ALL 12 MONTHS?  Or do I only need to do this in December when I balance the books for taxes?

Comment: I think you mixed the credit and debit there... What country are you in?

Comment: Sorry for the late upvote...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your account entries are generally correct, but do note that the last transaction is a mixture of the balance sheet and income statement.  If Quickbooks doesn't do this automatically then the expense must be manually removed from the balance sheet.

The expense should be recognized on the balance sheet and income statement when it accrues, and it accrues when the prepaid rent is extinguished when consumed by the landlord, so that is when the second entry in your question should be booked.

The cash flow statement will reflect all of these cash transactions immediately.

Comment: For tax purposes you can recognize prepaid expense in some cases, depending on the tax law. In the US, I believe, if you prepay up to a year, you can recognize it when paid. That's why I asked about the country.

Comment: @littleadv I leave tax to you and JoeTaxpayer.  I was only describing the financial accounting.  Rational financial accounting is universal, I find.  If the OP is looking for tax accounting, I'll delete.

Comment: No, why, your answer is fine, I was just adding to it

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  I live in the US, and need general accounting advice, I am an engineer trying to keep my own books in my new company.  Just to clarify, do I only need to do the adjustment in current assets at the end of each year (ie. the accounting period)?

Comment: @JustinCloud For financial purposes, the ideal is to keep the books "honest", so you'd want to get the prepaid rent off the books as soon as it has been properly removed from the landlord's books, eg when rent has actually been paid thus most likely monthly.  For the tax books, the accounts should be kept as optimally as possible for tax purposes in the way littleadv suggests and would suggest.  This situation is a good analogy to the situation that public corporations find themselves in: tax books, public financial books, private financial books.  We'll leave allowances to another question...

Comment: @Justin just out of curiosity, any particular reason you chose accrual based accounting for your business? As an engineer, you're likely providing services, not selling inventory... Why did you do that to yourself?

Comment: @littleadv In his defense, I will say that balance sheets get a little weird and difficult to produce with cash accounting.  I definitely second using cash accounting if available for taxes though.

Comment: My business will have inventory and products sold, so it is not just services.  Accrual is GAAP and I want my business to be friendly to investors, so setting this standard is good practice.  Thanks all for your input.

Comment: @JustinCloud Very wise.  I would consider keeping a third set of books that are as rational and honest as you can make them to have a better grasp on the true financial situation.  You will soon bang your head against the wall with gaap accounting almost as much as with tax.